# Can svn repo handle several connection protocols at the same time?

Tags: svn

I have Apache+mod_svn setup, and handle the `http` connection to my repos.

Can I use `file:` connection to repos simultaneously from server shell? Or I should use only `http://localhost/repo` from shell too?

Can it corrupt the repo data or commit index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Subversion can handle multiple protocols for one repository. You just need to make sure that your configurations stay in sync. For example if you're using HTTP & svn+ssh, you'll have to make sure your authorization rules match.

That said, use of `file://` is strongly discouraged. It's meant more for testing and single-user, desktop-only sorts of situations. Because using this protocol requires that any user accessing the repository have full permissions at the filesystem level and there's zero Subversion authentication/authorization, it's very easy for a user (or errant script) to delete things from the repository and/or corrupt it.

If you're set up to use HTTP to serve your repository, use that everywhere. Don't use `file://` because "I'm already on the server, it's *right there*."